# AWS ECS Green/Blue with CodePipeline: The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary taskset target group must be behind listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I've been trying for hours to get a basic CodePipeline up and running with ECS Green/Blue. We're creating a prototype, so everything is in a single repo for now, and the `Dockerfile`, `taskdef.json`, `appspec.yaml` are all in a subfolder. I'm getting the following error:

`The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary taskset target group must be behind listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123:listener/app/api-lb/123/123`

It's a standard pipeline:

1. CodeCommit
2. CodeBuild
3. CodeDeploy to ECS

Commit and Build work and I'm passing the artifacts to the last step. Deployment fails though, with the error mentioned above.

I have no idea what exactly the "primary taskset target group" is. Both target groups *are* behind a listener.

I know there are Terraform modules for this, but I wanted to modify/extend this after it works, so I decided to start from scratch. Went through a dozen different articles, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my ECS config.

I created a repo with all the files [here](https://github.com/zentered/terraform-ecs-green-blue-pipeline), here are the relevant the lb, ecs and CodeDeploy configs:

*lb*:

```
resource "aws_lb" "lb" {
  name               = "${var.name}-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = [aws_default_subnet.default_az1.id, aws_default_subnet.default_az2.id]
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.blue_green.id]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "blue" {
  name        = "${var.name}-blue"
  port        = 80
  target_type = "ip"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.lb
  ]
  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    interval            = "10"
    timeout             = "5"
    unhealthy_threshold = "3"
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.name
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "green" {
  name        = "${var.name}-green"
  port        = 80
  target_type = "ip"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.lb
  ]
  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    interval            = "10"
    timeout             = "5"
    unhealthy_threshold = "3"
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.name
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "green" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.lb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.green.arn
  }
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.green]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "blue" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.lb.arn
  port              = "8080"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue.arn
  }
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.blue]
}
```

*codedeploy*

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "app" {
  compute_platform = "ECS"
  name             = var.name
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "group" {
  app_name               = var.name
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
  deployment_group_name  = "${var.name}-group-1"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy-service.arn

  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }

  blue_green_deployment_config {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }

    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action = "TERMINATE"
    }
  }

  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }

  ecs_service {
    cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
    service_name = aws_ecs_service.api.name
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [aws_lb_listener.green.arn]
      }

      test_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [aws_lb_listener.blue.arn]
      }

      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.blue.name
      }

      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.green.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*ecs*:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = var.name

  configuration {
    execute_command_configuration {
      kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.keys.arn
      logging    = "OVERRIDE"

      log_configuration {
        cloud_watch_encryption_enabled = true
        cloud_watch_log_group_name     = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs.name
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "api" {
  family                   = "api"
  memory                   = 512
  cpu                      = 256
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-task-service.arn

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = var.name,
      image     = "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          "containerPort" = 8080,
          "hostPort"      = 8080
        }
      ],
      environment = [],
      log_options = {
        awslogs-region        = var.region
        awslogs-group         = var.name
        awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs-service"
      }
    }
  ])
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "api" {
  name            = var.name
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.api.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 1
  depends_on      = [aws_lb_listener.green, aws_lb_listener.blue, aws_iam_role_policy.ecs-service-base-policy]

  deployment_controller {
    type = "CODE_DEPLOY"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.blue.arn
    container_name   = var.name
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [aws_default_subnet.default_az1.id, aws_default_subnet.default_az2.id, aws_default_subnet.default_az3.id]
    security_groups = [
      aws_security_group.ecs.id
    ]
    assign_public_ip = false
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      load_balancer,
      desired_count,
      task_definition
    ]
  }
}
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlaying issue was an IAM permission error. After clicking through the stack, the "tasks" in the cluster didn't start because of missing permissions/roles.